# How to upload Audio file to my server?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a xamarin forms application, I am using dependency service to pick multiple files from device. I have written the following code for getting the actual file from Android.Net.Uri:

```
private string GetPathToAudioFile(global::Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        string doc_id = "";
        using (var c1 = ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null))
        {
            c1.MoveToFirst();
            String document_id = c1.GetString(0);
            doc_id = document_id.Substring(document_id.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        }

        string path = null;

        // The projection contains the columns we want to return in our query.
        string audioSelection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
        using (var cursor = ManagedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, audioSelection, new string[] { doc_id }, null))
        {
            if (cursor == null) return path;
            var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
        }
        return path;
    }
```

But whenever, I try to do this I get the following exception. [Cursor Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSWrA.png)

I am new to Xamarin and I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you need `GetPathToAudioFile` for? what you need is `Uri`, not `File` or "file path"

Comment: I have used uri, but it is only giving me path like this "/document/7". I also want the name of file with path but it doesn't return. How can I fix that?

Comment: `DocumentProvider` does not have to serve local files only and there is no such thing like "local file path", more: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html. so what do you really want to achieve with that "path"?

Comment: I want to extract file name, and I want to upload it on my server. How can I do that?

Comment: so use `ContentResolver` API, the name comes from the `Cursor` obtained by calling  `ContentResolver#query` method, the column name is: `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME`

Comment: Thank you. I have received the name of the file, but still I can't get the path so that I can upload it on my server.

Comment: just open your Uri using ContentResolver, read the docs first